# Multiple conditions for different values in the same column in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, algorithm

I have the following SQL database tables.

`qualificationTable`:

```
QualId studentRegNo CourseName   Percentage

1       1           A            91 
2       1           B            81
3       1           C            71
4       1           D            61
5       2           A            91
6       2           B            81
7       2           C            71
8       2           D            70
```

`testTable`:

```
TestId  studentRegNo testNo  Percentage dateTaken

1       1           1       91         2016-05-02
2       1           2       81         2015-05-02
3       1           3       71         2016-04-02
4       1           1       95         2014-05-02
5       1           2       43         2016-01-02
6       1           3       78         2015-05-02
7       2           1       80         2016-05-02
8       2           2       99         2016-05-02
9       2           3       87         2016-05-02
```

I have the minimum percentages specified for courses A, B, C and D individually. I need to search for students, meeting the minimum criteria for ALL the courses.

Part-2:
That student should also match the criteria (minimum percentages specified individually for the three tests- 1,2 and 3) in testTable.

In other words, if a student matches the minimum criteria (percentage) specified individually for all the courses, he should be selected. Now, same goes for the testTable, that particular student (who got selected in qualificationTable) should have the minimum criteria (percentage) specified individually for the three tests (1,2 and 3) in  testNo column.

**Edit:**

I have updated the testTable, now there are multiple tests for a particular student. I need to check if the student meets the minimum required percentage specified for all the 3 tests, however, only the most recently taken test in each no (1,2 and 3) should count. If the student does not meet the minimum criteria specified for the most recent test, he should not be included.

**Test Case:**

Minimum qualification percentage required:

> Course A: 90 Course B: 80 Course C: 70 Course D: 60

Minimum tests percentage required:

> Test 1: 90 Test 2: 80 Test 3: 70

**Expected Output**

```
studentNo

2
```

I have this so far:

```
SELECT stdqualificationmaster.studentRegNo
FROM 
( SELECT studentRegNo FROM stdqualificationmaster
  WHERE (CourseName = 'High School' AND Percentage >= 90)
  OR (CourseName = 'Intermediate' AND Percentage >= 80)
  OR (CourseName = 'BCA' AND Percentage >= 70)
  OR (CourseName = 'MCA' AND Percentage >= 60)
  GROUP BY studentRegNo
  HAVING COUNT(1) = 4
) stdqualificationmaster JOIN
( SELECT studentRegNo FROM testmaster
  WHERE (testLevel = '1' AND Percentage >= 90)
  OR (testLevel = '2' AND Percentage >= 80)
  OR (testLevel = '3' AND Percentage >= 70)
  GROUP BY studentRegNo
  HAVING COUNT(1) = 3
) testmaster ON stdqualificationmaster.studentRegNo = testmaster.studentRegNo;
```

**MySQLFiddle**

```
CREATE TABLE qualificationmaster
    (`QualId` int, `studentRegNo` int, `CourseName` varchar(1), `Percentage` int)
;

INSERT INTO qualificationmaster
    (`QualId`, `studentRegNo`, `CourseName`, `percentage`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A', 91),
    (2, 1, 'B', 81),
    (3, 1, 'C', 71),
    (4, 1, 'D', 61),
    (5, 2, 'A', 91),
    (6, 2, 'B', 81),
    (7, 2, 'C', 71),
    (8, 2, 'D', 70)
;


CREATE TABLE testmaster
    (`TestId` int, `studentRegNo` int, `testNo` int, `Percentage` int)
;

INSERT INTO testmaster
    (`TestId`, `studentRegNo`, `testNo`, `Percentage`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 91),
    (2, 1, 2, 81),
    (3, 1, 3, 71),
    (4, 1, 1, 95),
    (5, 1, 2, 43),
    (6, 1, 3, 78),
    (7, 2, 1, 80),
    (8, 2, 2, 99),
    (9, 2, 3, 87)
;
```

Cheers

Comment: Any chance of an sqlfiddle?

Comment: I'm still confused about how tests and course qualifications relate.